# is there a shorter way for this condition?

Tags: javascript

```
if (form.a.value !=""&&form.b.value!="" &&form.c.value !="")
```

is there a shorter way for this condition?

Comment: what is "form"? what are "a","b" and "c"?

Comment: Uh, why ask if you're not willing to answer basic questions?

Comment: I think it is not neccesery for my question

Comment: well i wanted to know if you wanted to reduce the number of verifications.. like, if "form" has a,b,c,d,e,f,g,etc elements maybe there's a way to loop over that instead of writing a very long "IF".. but i dont know what is form, a variable?, an HtmlElement?.. maybe is just me =P but i do need to know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javascript is weakly-typed so you can treat empty string as boolean false, so the following code should work:

```
if (form.a.value && form.b.value && form.c.value) {
```

However I don't know why would you want to change that code. Actually it's quite clear and verbose.

Comment: because it is verbose :), is there shorter way ?

Comment: Write your code for readability and maintainability. Run it through a minimizer before deployment.

Comment: @patrick dw: Oh, you’re right. Taking a look at the specification revealed that a [string value is only false if the length is zero](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-9.2).

Answer (score 2):

If you have only three fields(or less), you can leave it as is. If you have more(or unknown) number of fields to check, create an array of fields to check and do the checks in loop in separate function for better maintainability. Something like this:

```
if(!Empty([form.a,form.b,form.c]))
{
...
}

function Empty(elements)
{
    for(var i=0;i<elements.length;i++)
    {
        if(elements[i].value)
            return false;      
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

there are lazy ways :)

```
if(form.a.value + form.b.value + form.c.value != "" )

if(form.a.value.length + form.b.value.length + form.c.value.length != 0 )

if(!form.a.value && !form.b.value && !form.c.value)
```